# Kolmogorov-smirnov test in a matrix

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov

## r code

```
B = 10
CC <- numeric(B)
for(j in 1:10)
  N = rnorm(1000)
  print(ks.test(N,pnorm)$statistic)
  CC[j] <- ks.test(N,pnorm)$statistic
  print(CC[j])
print(CC)
```

if you run this in r you will get a matrix with 9 zeros and only the last term is an actually numeric value. Can someone please explain why this is happening and how can i get the numerical values on the other indices.

Answer (score 2):

It could be because of missing `{}`. Try this:

```
B = 10
CC <- numeric(B)
for(j in 1:10) {
  N = rnorm(1000)
  print(ks.test(N,pnorm)$statistic)
  CC[j] <- ks.test(N,pnorm)$statistic
  print(CC[j])
}
print(CC)
```